# Spring Integration error-channel doesn't receive all exceptions

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, spring-integration

I am using spring integration's error channel to capture exceptions in the framework. But of the two channels of the same type, one's thrown exceptions are received by the error handler while other's are not.

```html
    
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="com.si.MyGateway" request-
channel="myRequestChannel" error-channel="errorHandlingChannel">
<!-- Redirects exceptions to error-channel -->            
<int:chain input-channel="myRequestChannel" output-channel="lastChannel">
            <int:header-enricher>
                <int:error-channel ref="errorHandlingChannel">
            <int:header-enricher>
            <int:service-activator ref="testActivator1" 
method="generateException" requires-reply="true" />
            </int:chain>
<!-- Does not redirect exceptions to error-channel -->
                <int:chain input-channel="lastChannel" output-
channel="nullChannel">
            <int:header-enricher>
                <int:error-channel ref="errorHandlingChannel">
            <int:header-enricher>
            <int:service-activator ref="testActivator2" 
method="generateException" requires-reply="true" />
<int:filter ref="myFilter" discard-channel="nullChannel" />
            <int:service-activator ref="testActivator3" 
method="generateException" requires-reply="true" />
<int:filter ref="myFilter" discard-channel="nullChannel" />
            </int:chain>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorHandlingChannel" 
ref="errorHandler" method="handle" />
```

The errorHandler's handle method accepts MessagingException. When I throw exception from myRequestChannel, it is received by the errorHandler but when the same exception is thrown from testActivator2 or testActivator3, it doesn't reach the errorHandler at all.

both channels are defined as async channels:

```html
<int:channel>
<int:queue capacity="10">
</int:channel>
```

On debugging, I found that all methods' exceptions are being thrown and follow a chain through spring's classes when an internal class ultimately throws a MessagingException, but the exceptions from the last two activators do not reach the handler.

What could be the reason?

Comment: this could resolve your problem http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/72082-error-channel-service-activator

Comment: Thanks, but all my channels are async, so the solution mentioned in the link is already implemented but to no avail.

Comment: You don't need the `header-enricher`s - the gateway will automatically set the `errorChannel` header. There's nothing obvious in your configuration; I suggest you enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration`; if you can't figure it out from the log, edit your question with the log.

Comment: @GaryRussell 
Thanks. I edited my question by adding filters after the service activator. Earlier, I was facing the issue because of a configuration mistake with my error-channel leading to silent failure. After I corrected that problem, I realized that the error was still not thrown to the error-channel for many chains. The exception from the Service-Activator first went to the filter which rejected the exception messages since the logic rejected all messages which weren't of particular type. I'm still not sure why the exception did not directly go to the error-channel.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exceptions do you throw?

If it is `MessagingException` it must be supplied with the `failedMessage`, otherwise the error is sent to the default `errorChannel` on the `<poller>`.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question by adding filters after the service activator. Earlier, I was facing the issue because of a configuration mistake with my error-channel leading to silent failure. After I corrected that problem, I realized that the error was still not thrown to the error-channel for many chains. The exception from the Service-Activator first went to the filter which rejected the exception messages since the logic rejected all messages which weren't of particular type. I'm still not sure why the exception did not directly go to the error-channel.